# Java Application communication with C++ application using Message Queue in Linux

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, message-queue

I have one C++ application which communicates over Message Queues with other C++ applications.

I am trying to create one Java Application that reads/writes (communicates) queue being used by C++ application.

I have looked on JNI but i dont want to call C++ routines from Java application. I would only be interested in accessing data being read/write by C++ application
Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: There is a possible answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879101/running-a-jna-example-with-posix-message-queues. Using sockets to communicate rather than message queues would be more portable and more Java friendly.

Comment: Which of the message queue are you used? May be it has Java implementation?

Comment: hi.. i have created message queue program in qt creator using c++.

Comment: "Message Queue" has few meanings. I guess  You use this word in sense "in-process" message. But the other meaning is very interesting, has huge position on the market: message brokers, many solution with main broker in Java with intercaces in C++, some with C/C++ kernel and interfaces to Java. These are solutions for many environments, many languages etc

Comment: "Message Queue" has few meanings. I guess  You use this word in sense "in-process" message. But the other meaning is very interesting, has huge position on the market: message brokers, many solution with main broker in Java with intercaces in C++, some with C/C++ kernel and interfaces to Java. These are solutions for many environments, many languages etc

Comment: Hi guys.. I have created a application that is communicating between c++ and Java . but now i am facing some new problem.. that i want to communicate my java application with c++ via message queue. and i dont know the coding style of jni.. like how to code openqueue and readqueue function in jni C++. please give me some link or any example..that make my work easy.thanks